# How can I get the row with a min value from a group and the associated values from another tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

So I have three tables (Products, Stock and ProductsBatches ) and I'm trying to get the batch that expires first (from ProductsBatches) for each product and some additional info from Products (like product name) and Stock (like total quantity)

I managed to get just the earliest date for each product but when I add some other columns and joins it messes it up and it gets me all sorts of dates.

```
PRODUCTS  TABLE: 

   | PRODUCT ID (PK)|  NAME  | PRICE |    
   |     1          | CHEESE | 12.0  |

STOCK TABLE :

   | PRODUCT ID (PFK)| TOTAL QUANTITY |
   |     1           |      100       |

PRODUCTS BATCHES TABLE:

   | PRODUCT ID (PFK) | BATCH (PFK) | BATCH QUANTITY | BATCH EXPIRY |    
   |     1            |   XYZ       |       50       |  2019-01-01  |
   |     1            |   XZZ       |       50       |  2020-01-01  |
```

So far I've got:

```
| PRODUCT ID | BATCH EXPIRY |
|            |              |
|     1      | 2019-01-01   |
```

With  `SELECT productID,min(batchExpiry) from PRODUCTSBATCHES group by (productID)`

What I need:

```
|PRODUCT ID| NAME |TOTAL QUANTITY|PRICE|BATCH|BATCH QUANTITY|BATCH EXPIRY|
|     1    |CHEESE|        100   |12.0 | XYZ |  50          | 2019-01-01 |
```

I tried this but is also not good :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.productID) b.productID, p.name, s.totalquantity, 
p.price, b.batch, b.batchquantity, b.batchExpiry 
FROM productsbatches as b 
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT productID,min(batchExpiry) from PRODUCTSBATCHES group by (productID)
) as exmin b.productID = exmin.productID 
INNER JOIN stock as s ON b.productID = s.productID 
INNER JOIN products as p ON s.productID = p.productID
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but you forgot to join the `batchExpiry` column with the min `batchExpiry` derived by the subquery:

```
SELECT 
  p.productID, p.name, s.totalquantity, 
  p.price, b.batch, b.batchquantity, b.batchExpiry
FROM products as p
INNER JOIN stock as s ON p.productID = s.productID 
INNER JOIN productsbatches as b ON p.productID = b.productID 
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT productID, min(batchExpiry) as batchExpiry 
  FROM PRODUCTSBATCHES 
  GROUP BY productID
) as exmin ON b.productID = exmin.productID AND b.batchExpiry = exmin.batchExpiry
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT ON` is the right way to go.  You just have to use it correctly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.productID) p.productID, p.name, s.totalquantity, 
       p.price, b.batch, pb.batchquantity, pb.batchExpiry
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     stock s
     ON p.productID = s.productID INNER JOIN
     productsbatches pb
     ON pb.productID = p.productID 
ORDER BY p.productID, pb.batchExpiry;
```

Basically, all you need is the `ORDER BY`.  The subquery is not necessary.

Comment: In my actual data base I have two productsBatches tables for two different kind of products and I used this with union with productsBatchesNo2 and I don't seem to get the first expiry batch. However when using forpas's solution I'm getting two rows if there are two batches from the same product with the same expiry date. So I've combined the two answers and I added DISTINCT to the solution and got what I wanted. Thank you for the answer !